# Invisible Writing

Tags: code-golf

In the physical world, invisible ink usually becomes invisible when it dries, and is then is readable if it is exposed to heat or chemicals of some kind. The invisible ink in this challenge will be readable when exposed to highlighting.

Create a full program or function that takes in text from the console (using a prompt) and outputs it the console so it cannot be seen unless highlighted (selected, as you would with a mouse).

[image]

[image]

### Notes:

- Assume that the console is a solid color (black, white, green, etc.).

This is code golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

Comment: Isn't this requirement heavily platform-dependent?

Comment: @FelixPalmen in what way?

Comment: different consoles in different operating systems have different ways how to control them, so if a solution doesn't use a language with integrated terminal/console control functions, it would need to also specify what OS and terminal/console it is targeting.

Comment: @FelixPalmen hmm, makes sense. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: Or you could specify it like e.g. "*the output should use standard ANSI terminal control sequences*"

Comment: IDK if this is a problem ... maybe when it comes to comparing the solutions ....

Comment: Is there a maximum length for the input ?

Comment: Couldn't we just assume our console uses a black background with black foreground, but the highlight color is white?

Comment: @HatsuPointerKun No, there is not.

Comment: @miles I decided against that because then you could just output black text.

Comment: What counts as highlighting? Selecting the text? Changing the colour after printing? Changing the background colour?

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Selecting the text. I will update the challenge.

Comment: HTML, 28 bytes: `<input style="color:white"/>`

Comment: @BetaDecay, simple `white` is not enough, because for example Firefox's text input has a gray gradient background: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7Dz6.png Better this: `<input style=color:#fff0>`

Comment: Bah, Batch specifically guards against outputting invisible text...

Comment: @manatwork; it only needs to work in *one* browser in order to be valid.

Comment: @CalebKleveter I can copy the content in the console in a text file to reveal the output. Does this counts as highlighting ? Because highlighting in the windows console will change both foreground and background colors ( so black foreground and black background will become white foreground and white background ), and i can't prevent it

Comment: @manatwork Well how about this: `<input style="color:white;background:white"/>`?

Comment: @Shaggy, possible. Not sure what the question owner's [comment on a solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/135852/invisible-writing?noredirect=1#comment332282_135864) wants to mean. I interpreted as the 1 working environment is not enough here.

Comment: @BetaDecay, if you set both colors yourself, then maybe `<input style=color:red;background:red>`.

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>44</s> 42 bytes

Tested in Chrome & Firefox.

```js
s=>console.log("%c"+s,"color:transparent")
```

---

### Try it

Open your browser's console.

```js
(
s=>console.log("%c"+s,"color:transparent")
)("Invisible Text!")
```

---

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>21</s> 20 bytes

Will post this separately when/if the challenge is reopened

```
Ol"%c"+U`¬l:ÉspÂÁt
```

[Test it](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=T2wiJWMiK1VgrGyOOsmYc3DCwXQ=&input=IkludmlzaWJsZSBUZXh0Ig==)

Comment: I can't see the text if I highlight it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAVhS.png

Comment: Try a different browser, @CalebKleveter. Also, no need to paste it into your console, you can just run the Snippet above.

Comment: This works fine in the javascript-console of Chromium. But @CalebKleveter -- see what I meant with *heavily platform-dependent* ;)

Answer (score 1):

### [Magneson](https://github.com/UnderMybrella/Magneson), 102 bytes

[image: Visible version of the program]
<sub>(source: [googleapis.com](https://storage.googleapis.com/brella-archives/Code%20Golf/Magneson/always_invisible_ink_visible.png))</sub>

(Note that the above is an enlarged version of the program, and the action source can be found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210507031700/https://storage.googleapis.com/brella-archives/Code%20Golf/Magneson/always_invisible_ink.png)

This is my first submission in a long while, so while I think Magneson does classify as a language according to [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073), if it's not suitable let me know and I can take it down.

Onto the "code" itself; Magneson operates by parsing an image and evaluating commands from the colours of the pixels it reads. So stepping through the image for this challenge, we have:

- `R: 0, G: 0, B: 1` is a simple `println` statement; it prints a string out to the console
- `R: 255, G: 255, B: 0` is a string operative to concatenate the following values, until we receive a stop concatenate op.
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 27` is a raw character. In strings, when the red component is `2` and the green component is `0`, we simply use the blue component as a raw character to add to the string. In this case, we add the escape character for ANSI control strings.
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 91` is another raw character (`[`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 51` is another raw character (`3`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 48` is another raw character (`0`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 59` is another raw character (`;`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 52` is another raw character (`4`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 48` is another raw character (`0`)
- `R: 2, G: 0, B: 109` is another raw character (`m`)
- `R: 3, G: 0, B: 0` is a string operative for input from STDIN. In this case, it just appends it to the concatenated string.
- `R: 255, G: 255, B: 1` is the end concatenation op.

  All in all, this program builds a string of `ESC[30;40m`, followed by one line of input from the command line. This'll set both the foreground and background colours to black.

Comment: This doesn't work when the background colour is not black

Comment: Just saw that requirement (Error on my part). Updated to account for that

Comment: Not really sure how to test this but when you select the text can you see it?

Comment: It does on my system at least, since it's just using ANSI control codes

Comment: same general problem as with my solution, you just can't control (with ANSI escape sequences) what a terminal actually does when displaying a selection. I'll try a few terminals soon and can hopefully add a list of some supported ones to my solution (windows 10 console is not among them)

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <strike>77</strike> 91 bytes

```c
c;main(){printf("\x1b]11;2\a\x1b[42;32m");while((c=getchar())>0)putchar(c);puts("\x1b[m");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBDsIgFAWv8tMVLEwE3RE9hbvWBf1SQEtBCrZqPDu26W5e5g3uNGIpKJy0A6HfEO2QOlI1M2uvjAneyBXrIxcH7ioqJmN7RQietEpoZCSUnvc05G0gFQuOW1@v/18pF6PgmS0@oI1@GqDzM9yzCyP4l4qQFt3LzxtuXv8B) (will only show the raw output including the escape sequences)

Extra bytes were necessary to be independent from the original background color, see discussion in the comments.

This version uses ANSI escape codes to set the background and foreground colors to green as well as an Xterm escape code to change the background of the whole window to green. This way, if your selection color doesn't happen to be (dark) green (very unlikely), it **will** work on terminals supporting ANSI escape sequences and compatible with Xterm.

It works for example in `rxvt` as seen in these screenshots:

[image: before running]
[image: after running]
[image: after running with selection]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this doesn't work for the reasons you have stated.

Comment: As stated, whether it works or not depends on how the terminal handles selection display. It **doesn't** work on a windows console, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes but you've also hard coded the colour, what happens when the background is white?

Comment: It doesn't bother me that it doesn't work on a windows console. What I did notice was that you said it only works on a black background. A solution should work on any solid colored terminal.

Comment: @CalebKleveter in this case, it must either be allowed to change the background color as well or there's no solution for terminals that can *only* be controlled by ANSI sequences.

Comment: I never put in the challenge that you can't change the terminal color. I never thought of that, so you can use it to your advantage.

Comment: @CalebKleveter fixed with a solution doing *exactly* that, but in green. Still requires some specific support from the terminal, works e.g. (as stated) with `rxvt`.

Comment: 82 bytes `main(c){for(printf("\e]11;2\a\e[42;32m");~(c=getchar());)putchar(c);puts("\e[m");}`